# Create security groups from list of CIDR

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group

I tried to create ingress rule for each value in my list:

```
private_subnets_cidr_blocks = [
  "10.0.10.0/24",
  "10.0.11.0/24",
  "10.0.12.0/24",
]
```

I import the list from a vpc module. I try to create the ingress for each value in a eks managed node group:

```
  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    bottlerocket = {
      ...
      create_security_group          = true
      security_group_name            = "sgr-eks-managed-node-groups"
      security_group_rules = {
        ingress = {
          for_each    = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.private_subnets_cidr_blocks[*]
          protocol    = "tcp"
          from_port   = 9443
          to_port     = 9443
          type        = "ingress"
          cidr_blocks = each.value.data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.private_subnets_cidr_blocks[*]
        }
    }
  }
```

But I have the following error:

```
A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in its "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your configuration to work around this error.
```

Is important for security team use least privileges, I cant use all vpc CIDR, I only can use the private CIDR subnet

Comment: `cidr_blocks` attribute should be something like this `cidr_blocks = each.value`. This `each.value.data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.private_subnets_cidr_blocks[*]` does not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in not working with `cidr_blocks = each.value`. The error is: `Error: each.value cannot be used in this context. A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in its "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your configuration to work around this error.`

Comment: What is this `security_group_rules` ? Is it a `variable` or `local`, or something else?

Comment: In that case that should probably be a [`dynamic`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks)  block, otherwise `for_each` wont work. Although, at this point it is not really clear for me what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I update the post with more information. Is important for security team use least privileges, I cant use all vpc CIDR, I only can use the private CIDR subnets.

Comment: What is the full context of where you are using `eks_managed_node_groups`? Can you provide complete code?